# heroku getting started guide project not working with 'heroku local'

Tags: node.js, heroku, local

After cloning the directory then running 'heroku local'

the only output is:

```
 forego | starting web.1 on port 5000 

 web.1  | module.js338
```

the process does not show up in the process list. 
accessing http://localhost:5000 returns ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I'm supposed to be able to just clone the directory then run heroku local.  What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed a step

$npm install

I didn't have the dependencies in the local directory.  This is basically node's build process.